# How to not allow duplication in react-select

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and learning how to use react-select. Moreover, I wanted to ensure that only unique values are put into input field but with the code below does not allow me to achieve that and also used indexOf but no result thus I really need your help:

```
const onSelectAll = () => {
                    const filteredOptions = options.filter(option => {
                        return filterOption(option as any, inputValue)
                    });
                    const uniqueValues = filteredOptions.filter((item,i)=>{
                          filteredOptions.indexOf(item)===i
                    })
                    setValue([...value, ...uniqueValues], setValueAction);
                };
```

The above onSelectAll function is click handler for "Select all" button which adds all corresponding valus that user typed in from menu into react-select input.

Comment: Please add a snippet or specify your edge case to clarify the bloker and what is happening.

Comment: @mdiiorio, in a nutshell, please can you tell me ways to achieve that only unique values are selected and put into react-select input?